# Returning ploneformgen errors back to restricted users

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I have a ploneformgen form that we use for event creation. It's necessary... trust me.  The users using the form have local roles for adding content (through the sharing tab) and are not admin users.  The form carries the permissions to process the event. Invariably my users do something that throws a system error (event with the same name, paste an illegal character in the title, etc).  It would be handy if my users could see the traceback, but I'm unsure how to enable that or if it's even possible?  Any hints?

Comment: If you know what your users are doing wrong (illegal character in title) you can maybe validate the form input and show a good error message. Or you can correct it (e.g. by removing illegal characters or adding an number to file name)?

Comment: It's never handy to show a traceback to a enduser. As @mara commented: Imlement a validator. FormGen fields supports a validator expression.

Comment: FWIW, if you generate temporary names that look look like the ones `portal_factory` uses, you get the automatic rename based on title.

Comment: hmm. . I didn't think about generating temp names and using the framework to get the automatic rename. I've actually switched the shortname to a timestamp, which solves part of the problem. I guess I'll write a custom validator for the rest of the errors. I had a feeling that was the real answer anyway.